# R bank statement grouping

Tags: r, inner-join, banking

I'm analyzing my bank statements by grouping purchases by retailer name, the resulting data frame can then be analysed using `dplyr` functions. My method below uses a custom function and works, but I'm curious to know if there is a more efficient method. For example are there any packages that can join dataframes using complex matching logic between dataframe columns?

```
debug(FindRetailer)

FindRetailer<-function(Purchase){
    P <- toupper(Purchase)
  for(z in 1:length(RetailerNames)){
    Retailer<-toupper(RetailerNames[z])
    HasFound=grepl(Retailer,P)
    if(HasFound==TRUE){
      return(str_to_title(Retailer))
    }
  }
    return("Donno")
}

Statement <- data.frame(
  Purchase = c("abc Aldi xyz","a Kmart bcd","a STARBUCKS ghju","abcd MacD efg"),
  Amount = c(235,23,789,45))

RetailerNames<- c("Aldi","Kmart","Starbucks","MacD")

# what I need
Result <- data.frame(
  Purchase = c("abc Aldi xyz","a KMART bcd","a STARBUCKS mmm","abcd MACD efg"),
  Amount = c(235,23,789,45),
  Retailer = c("Aldi","Kmart","Starbucks","Macd"))

# this works using custom function
NewStatment<-Statement %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(Retailer=FindRetailer(Purchase))

# is this possible: join dataframes using complex string matching?
# this doesn't work yet
TestMethod<-Statement %>% 
  left_join(RetailerNames,by="Statement.Purchase %in% RetailerNames")
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(glue) 
Statement <- data.frame(
  Purchase = c("abc Aldi xyz","a Kmart bcd","a STARBUCKS ghju","abcd MacD efg"),
  Amount = c(235,23,789,45))

RetailerNames<- c("Aldi","Kmart","Starbucks","MacD")


Statement %>% 
  mutate(
    Retailer = Purchase %>% 
      str_extract(RetailerNames %>% collapse(sep ="|") %>% regex(ignore_case = T))
    )
#>           Purchase Amount  Retailer
#> 1     abc Aldi xyz    235      Aldi
#> 2      a Kmart bcd     23     Kmart
#> 3 a STARBUCKS ghju    789 STARBUCKS
#> 4    abcd MacD efg     45      MacD
```

If you want to go the `left_join` route, try

```r
library(fuzzyjoin)

RetailerNames<- data_frame(Retailer = c("Aldi","Kmart","Starbucks","MacD"))

Statement %>%
  regex_left_join(RetailerNames, by = c(Purchase="Retailer"))
```

Comment: Thanks I thought there would be a simple solution. I'll take a look at ``fuzzyjoin`` also

Comment: I edited the solution because my original only worked because of a lucky coincidence. My current solution involves collapsing the retailer names vector into a regular expression string

Comment: Thanks for the correction and the fuzzy logic method

Comment: pleasure. This just goes to show how tricky it can sometimes be to create a good reproducible example. Your example was great, but it was the only situation my original solution would've worked on...